# See if input is a Integer in a Defined Function

Tags: python, function, while-loop, user-defined-functions, valueerror

So I'm making this recipe converter program with Python that multiplies or divides your recipe by a certain number. I'm at a point where I made these few lines of code that check if the required amount for an ingredient is an integer or not:

```
while True:
    try:
        amount = int(input(f"Enter in the amount for {ingredient}: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a number")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

While this does work for checking if it's a number, I repeat this part of the code a few times throughout my program to check if a specific input is a number or not. Is there a way to make a defined function to check if it's an integer? For example (***If it could be like this***):

```
amount = int(input(f"Enter in the amount for {ingredient}: "))
check_int(amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Factoring out the check alone won't do you much good (because you want to prompt again until they provide a valid `int`), so factor out both the check and the loop to a function:

```
def prompt_for_int(prompt_str=None, error_str='This is not an integer'):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt_str))
        except ValueError:
            print(error_str, flush=True)
```

then at point of use you just see:

```
amount = prompt_for_int(f"Enter in the amount for {ingredient}: ")
```

Comment: I think I understand (Again, I'm just a beginner going onto Intermediate with python). So I would have to have the def function (as you wrote it) be equal to the variable (amount) which is also as you show it.

Comment: @AlecSmith: That's an odd way to describe it; you're not "making the function equal to a variable", you're "assigning the result (return value) from calling a function to a variable". Saying "be equal" makes it sound like a comparison; think of `=` as "assignment", not "equals", or you'll get confused when it comes to `==` (which is an equality test). But yes, verbiage aside, I think you understand; you define a function once that can be reused elsewhere. When called, that function does not return until the user provides a valid `int`, at which point you assign what it returns appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_int(value):

    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
    
print(check_int(2))
print(check_int("2"))
```

A function that tries to cast the input value to be an integer. If it can cast it, it means that it is an integer, otherwise it is not an integer. If you want to handle floats too, you will need to make more changes to this.